# How to set up a scrape with the scraped_resource gem?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, rubygems

I discovered the scraped_resource gem, which sounds like a great way to do screen scraping. How do you create a scraper using this gem? It's brand new, so I haven't been able to find any docs.

http://github.com/hasclass/scraped_resource
http://yopefonic.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/ruby-and-rails-2010-report/

Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to web scraping and open to alternatives, then better to use an established library. In the ruby world [scrubyt](http://www.rubyinside.com/scrubyt-hot-new-ruby-web-scraping-toolkit-released-378.html) is popular.